# Difference in construction of controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I have seen controllers coded in two different ways.

This way:

```
myApp.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
        // code here
    }]);
```

And this way:

```
myApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    // code here
});
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just allows it so that when minification is done, Angular will be able to keep reference to the actual dependency. So that if

```
myApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $location, MyService) {
    // code here
});
```

is minified, it would become something like:

```
myApp.controller('SearchCtrl',function(a,b,c){//code here});
```

And since there's no such thing as providers for a, b, and c, Angular would crap out. When you add the square brackets and its minified, it becomes something like:

```
myApp.controller('SearchCtrl',['$scope', '$location', 'MyService',function(a,b,c){//code here}]);
```

And Angular knows to map $scope -> a, $location -> b, and MyService -> c.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So that been said, it's good practice to use the references version then?

Comment: absolutely, if you're minifying. the good news is, if you're using grunt or gulp, there is ngmin which will take care of it for you. It's made by Brian Ford who works on Angular: https://github.com/btford/ngmin

Comment: apparently ngmin has been depracated in favor of ng-annotate: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate (grunt package: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ng-annotate, gulp package: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ng-annotate)

Answer (score 0):

The array syntax is used to allow minifying the code. If this is not used and the code is minified, `$scope` and `$location` might be renamed by the minifier and thus dependency injection would fail.